# Debugging code with dojo.require in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, debugging, dojo, remote-debugging, webstorm

I am trying to remotely debug a web application with WebStorm 6. The application uses dojo.require to load scripts. All scripts are loaded by the browser and my application runs fine.

However, I can only place breakpoints in the main Javascript file that contains all the dojo.require statements. The scripts that are loaded dynamically by dojo.require do not show up in the 'Scripts' window and breakpoints in those files are - understandably - ignored. The 'Scripts' window only shows my main file and some dojo scripts (bootstrap, base, dojo).

How can I teach WebStorm to see the dynamically loaded Javascript as real scripts so that breakpoints in them will trigger?